# Reverse filter_var function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, filter-var

When I enter info into DB, I'm using a filter_var function to protect my DB from SQL Injection: `filter_var($visitor_name, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);` So if I enter, for example, O'Hara, in the DB it's stored as `O&#39;Hara`.
When I retrieve this data from the DB and output it as HTML, everything is OK, it's shown as O'Hara. But if I want to put it in a text input field for editing, I see it just as in the DB - `O&#39;Hara`. So how can I sort of reverse the filter_var action, so in the input fields I would also see it normally, as O'Hara?

This is the code I use to retrieve the data:

```
function edit_visitor(visitor_id)
{
    $.getJSON("inc/API.php",
    {
        command : "get_visitor_by_id",
        visitor_id : visitor_id
    }, function(result){
        $("#edt_visitor_name").attr('value', result[0].visitor_name);
        $("#edt_visitor_identity_num").attr('value', result[0].visitor_identity_num);
        $("#edt_visitor_phone").attr('value', result[0].visitor_phone);
        $("#edt_visitor_email").attr('value', result[0].visitor_email);
        $("#edt_visitor_event_date").attr('value', result[0].visitor_event_date);
    });
}
```

Comment: That's not the way to protect yourself from SQL-injections. I would recommend using PDO and prepared statements for that. You should always store your data unformatted and only format it when outputted to client, not format it on insert (as it can give you headaches like you've noticed).

Answer (score 0):

Use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) in `PHP` to convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters

```
html_entity_decode($a);
```

OR in javascript with `phpjs` library

[html_entity_decode using phpjs](http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode/)

Comment: I tried the html_entity_decode like that: `I tried it like that: `html_entity_decode(json_encode(select("SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE visitor_id = $str_visitor_id")), ENT_QUOTES);` For some reason it works only with ENT_QUOTES, if I try to use ENT_HTML5, ENT_XHTML, ENT_HTML401 or no flag at all - I don't get any result.
I tried the JS as well: copied the function to my script and called it like that: `$("#edt_visitor_name").attr('value', htmlspecialchars_decode(result[0].visitor_name));` but again - no result.

Comment: @Igal You are doing it in wrong way. Use `phpjs's` `html_entity_decode ` function in javascript where you received your data.

Comment: As I said, I tried to use the JS function, but it didn't work. What did I do wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)? If you want to do this in Javascript. In PHP I don't know how to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

use `htmlspecialchars_decode`

for example

```
 $clean_string = htmlspecialchars_decode($db_string);
```

Comment: I tried it like that: `htmlspecialchars_decode(json_encode(select("SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE visitor_id = $str_visitor_id")), ENT_QUOTES);` For some reason it works only with ENT_QUOTES, if I try to use ENT_HTML5, ENT_XHTML, ENT_HTML401 or no flag at all - I don't get any result. So only the quotes are converted back to normal chars. Is there a possibility to convert other chars as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: html_entity_decode() a more comprehensive version of htmlspecialchars_decode() (IN PHP).

In JavaScript:

> ```
> function htmlspecialchars_decode(string, quote_style) {  
>    var histogram = {}, symbol = '', tmp_str = '', entity = '';  
>    tmp_str = string.toString();  
>
>    if (false === (histogram = get_html_translation_table('HTML_SPECIALCHARS', quote_style))) {  
>        return false;  
>    }  
>
>    // &amp; must be the last character when decoding!  
>    delete(histogram['&']);  
>    histogram['&'] = '&amp;';  
>
>    for (symbol in histogram) {  
>        entity = histogram[symbol];  
>        tmp_str = tmp_str.split(entity).join(symbol);  
>    }  
>
>    return tmp_str;
> ```
>
> }

`How to use: htmlspecialchars_decode("<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>", 'ENT_NOQUOTES');`

Comment: I tried the JS code, but still got no result. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I copypasted this function to my script and then called it like that: `$("#edt_visitor_name").attr('value', htmlspecialchars_decode(result[0].visitor_name));`

Comment: Please red my new answer. I hope it will help you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290652/reverse-filter-var-function/17292677#17292677

Answer (score -1):

The best way to decode HTML is this:

`<script>`

`varTitle = $('<div />').html("Chris&apos; corner").text();`

`alert(varTitle);`

`</script>`

Comment: It needs JQuery... `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
I hope this will help you!